# Selenium(PYTHON) print only decimal value of a string

Tags: python, selenium, numbers, operators, webautomation

So i am looping through a bunch of strings, and i only want the decimal value of the text and have it read as an actual decimal and not a string, how would i get it, i have tried import re to substitute for the value, but it doesnt print the decimal, just gives me the numbers. What do i do?

```
string = "20.5k+"
stringVal= re.sub('[^0-9]', '', string)
print(Decimal(stringVal))
```

mind you i dont want to use a .Replace method, just grab only the decimal, maybe remove any text after k+

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing other examples, this works assuming the format of all of your strings follows the same pattern:

```py
string = "20.5k+"
stringVal= re.split('[a-z]', string)
print(float(stringVal[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `strip()` the unwanted characters as follows:

```
pqr = "20.5k+"
print(pqr.strip("k+"))
# prints: 20.5
```

---

### Alternative *(a)*

You can also `sub()` the `k` and `+` characters using the [re](/questions/tagged/re) module as follows:

```
import re
xyz = "20.5k+"
print(re.sub('[k+]', '', xyz))
# prints: 20.5
```

---

### Alternative *(b)*

You can also `replace()` the `k` and `+` characters as follows:

```
abc = "20.5k+"
print(abc.replace('k', '').replace('+', ''))
# prints: 20.5
```